# Passing self in a decorator with params

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am trying to set a decorator on a unit test, the purpose of the decorator is to ensure that a user logins in before accessing other endpoints.

Below is the decorator for logging in :

```
def login_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def login_user():
        kwargs['self'].client.login(
            username=kwargs['email'],
            password=kwargs['password'],
        )
```

Then am trying to utilize it on the unit test function as below :

```
@login_decorator(self=self, email=self.email, password=self.password)
    def test_customer_profile_add(self):
        response = super().create_customer_profile(self.customer_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

however `self` is underlines with an error Unresolved reference , how can I achieve passing of the params through the decorator with self.

Comment: There are many problems here. I think you would do well to start by reviewing a [general guide to writing decorators with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484) (link is to one of the "classic" highly-rated Stack Overflow answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your params to `login_user` function:

```py
def login_decorator(func):
    def login_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # function args
        print(self.username, self.password)
        self.client.login(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
        )
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

and your test function:

```py
@login_decorator
def test_customer_profile_add(self):
    response = super().create_customer_profile(self.customer_data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```